# Animate Blend Mode with opacity and transition

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode, background-blend-mode

I'm looking for a way to change the opacity of `background-color-blend-mode` like 
Photoshop. My goal is to animate the opacity of the blend-mode to make it disappear. Any ideas ?

```css
#img-esadvalence {
  background-image: url(http://leodurand.fr/works/planesad/esad1.jpg);
  background-color: #e12a1c;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}

.all-img-menu {
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 110%;
    padding-bottom: 40.75vh;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%); 
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-esadvalence" class="all-img-menu"></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to animate the image away (so that you see a red background in the end)? Or do you want to tween the blend-mode back to `normal`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blend mode only works when there are 2 backgrounds. To cancel the blend mode gradually, you can animate (transition) to a transparent background color.

**Demo** (hover the image to see the effect):

```css
#img-esadvalence {
  background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals);
  background-color: #e12a1c;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}


#img-esadvalence:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.all-img-menu {
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 110%;
    padding-bottom: 40.75vh;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%); 
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-esadvalence" class="all-img-menu"></div>
```